# How to change application that is used to open a file by ``QDesktopServices.openUrl``

Tags: qt, pyqt, debian, qt5, calibre

I'm trying to debug a problem with opening CBR files in Calibre (it was [explained here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225103/how-to-change-programs-used-to-handle-files-in-calibre-in-debian)). Specific Callibre problem is mostly not revelant, and it boild down to the issue that files and folders are opened by improper external programs.

After some debugging I found out that the culprit is most probably a call to `QDesktopServices.openUrl(qurl)` which selects wrong application to handle a specific file.

[Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) is somewhat laconic as to how this method works (I really care about Python version, but I guess that behaviour is identical):

> If the URL is a reference to a local file (i.e., the URL scheme is "file") then it will be opened with a suitable application instead of a Web browser.

My linux enviorment seems to be configured properly, if I double click on this file in Nautilus (I don't really have full KDE enviorment ready) it opens in a proper program.

So questions are:

- How does `openUrl` find proper application to open a file.
- How can I change what application will handle that file.

Comment: What specific Linux DE are you using? For qt5, desktop services are handled by platform integration plugins, and only a few DEs are supported by default. If calling `openUrl` with a valid local file url just returns `False` without printing any Qt debug messages, it most likely means there is no platform integration plugin available on your system. If that is the case, you can use [setUrlHandler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#setUrlHandler) to explicitly invoke something like [`xdg-open`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) (which is what most plugins would do anyway).

Comment: @ekhumoro I use debian with i3 window maganer. ``openUrl`` returns true, because it opens the file, however file is opened in an improper program (and a different program than one used by thunar and doplhin).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some additional research it turns out that `QDesktopServices.openUrl` uses XDG utulities under the hood. Results are consistent whith `xdg-open`.